# Is this type of closing a question valid?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The question [Can the Guna-Karma classification of the Varna system be translated into profession?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12320/can-the-guna-karma-classification-of-the-varna-system-be-translated-into-profess?noredirect=1#comment30598_12320) is close-voted as a duplicate of the question titled [K.S. Bhagavan's critique of Adi Shankara](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9196/k-s-bhagavans-critique-of-adi-shankara).

These are totally different questions. A part of one answer of the second question touches what is asked in the first. Is that a valid reason to close the first question?

My objection: If the question is closed, other good answers possible to it cannot be had, as the other question is totally different.

Comment: A question about hotel food was also closed as duplicate of a question on consumption of onion and garlic.They are two different questions. One may contain/subsume the other in which case the "smaller" question should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Agreed, but here neither question is a subset of the other. These are totally different questions.

Comment: The hotel question talks about consumption of onion and garlic too.

Comment: Eh, you are totally missing the point. I assume you have not gone through the above two questions.

Comment: Has it been reopened since? Cuz I'm not seeing it as a duplicate

Comment: @AmitSaxena Perhaps the questions (the examples I gave) got edited later. The hotel question DID include question on onion, garlic as well. Have you read the questions?

Comment: @moonstar2001 Ya, but it looks like you haven't read mine. Neither question contains another.

Comment: I completely agree, this question cannot be a duplicate. The former question is KS Bhagavan's critique. It is very specific to two people: Shankara and KS Bhagavan. This is a completely different question. it can have answers from Advaita, Vishisthadvaita, etc. If one question asks "what are the different endangered animals" and another question asks "what are the endangered lotus species in India", it is completely wrong to close the first question as a duplicate of the second question.

Comment: I don't think your question is a duplicate in any way of that K.S. Bhagavan question; an answer detailing the problems (if any) with K.S. Bhagavan's undertstading of the caste system and an answer discussing how jobs like engineer fit into the caste system can be completely different.  In any case, I think your question may well be a duplicate of other caste system questions on the site (I haven't checked), but not that one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***IMHO, This question should not be closed as a duplicate.***

Here is an example to illustrate

> > Q1:      What is the IMDB review of Harry Potter Sorcerer's stone movie?
> >
> > Q2:      What are the various reviews of JK Rowling's books?

The first question is specific, it deals with IMDB and Harry Potter part I.

The second question is broad. It deals with entire reviews of JK Rowling's books.

It is clear that Q1 will never be able to contain the answer to Q2?!

Similarly the question [K.S. Bhagavan's critique of Adi Shankara](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9196/k-s-bhagavans-critique-of-adi-shankara) is about Shankaracharya and K.S Bhagavan. It is very specific.

The question [Can the Guna-Karma classification of the Varna system be translated into profession?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/12320/can-the-guna-karma-classification-of-the-varna-system-be-translated-into-profess?noredirect=1#comment30598_12320) is about Varna system in general.

***I.E., Q1 cannot contain the answer to Q2!***

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I voted your question to be closed based on the following guidance from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/187039) and also because I believe @iammilind's [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/9202/2995) addresses the exact question you asked.

> **Questions may be duplicates if they have the same (potential) answers.** This includes not only word-for-word duplicates, but also the same idea expressed in different words.

So, yes, it is valid to close a question as duplicate of another although on the surface both appear to be totally different questions.

Comment: These questions do not have same potential answers.

Comment: If this question is closed, the only answer it will receive is K. S. Bhagavan's critique. What about other viewpoints? Or, what the scriptures say?

Comment: Please read the other question again, '1) what Bhagavan criticized in detail
2) what his arguments are, and **3) whether his critique is well-founded?**' - although it seems very specific, a good answer would have to delve into scriptures - so the other question already contains what you are asking in your question.

Comment: You could edit your question & link the other question and @iammilind's answer and explain clearly how it doesn't already address your question and what more you are looking for. In its current form, it would lead to lot of redundancy and copy-paste type of answers affecting the quality of the site.

Comment: Also, see some popular comments on this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37466/187039). "It's tiresome seeing the same answers again and again" and "We still need some duplicate questions around **to cover users who have the uncanniest ability to ask the same exact question using zero words in common.**"